# Como deixar uma imagem responsiva sem o uso de frameworks?

Tags: css, css3, imagem

Estou com a seguinte dúvida:

Tenho a seguinte imagem em um arquivo PSD.

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Estou utilizando Bootstrap para desenvolver o sistema, porém precisava que esta imagem fosse feita com CSS e ficasse responsivo.

Alguma sugestão ?

Obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

```
img{
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 300px; /* coloque aqui o tamanho real da imagem em px */
}
```

Assim a imagem vai se adequar ao seu box, porém seu box também deve estar 100%.

Exemplo:

```
<div style="width: 100%">
   <img style="width: 100%; max-width: 300px;" src="imagem.png">
</div>
```

Fiz CSS Inline para te mostrar, mas pode ser do outro jeito.

Comment: Então Diego, até funciona! Porém os textos seriam variáveis, precisava que os textos se ajustassem conforme a página fosse redimensionada.

Comment: Use `media queries`, ou deixe a fonte também com `100%`. `font-size: 100%`. Você não explicou isso na sua pergunta, só falou de imagem...

Comment: ola, tens de fazer isso a la pata...@media screen and (max-width: 640px) { } algo deste genero e coloca este codigo que queres

Comment: o uso de media queries pode resolver seu problema

Answer (score 0):

O que se pode fazer é definir a imagem com essas propriedades.

```css
img{
width:100%;
height:auto;
}
```

Assim ocupará toda a largura do elemento que a contém. Para poder limitar esse tamanho da imagem quando em telas maiores ou menores você poder usar grid view. Dê uma olha em : https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_grid.asp

E como já foi falado podem também usar **media queries**